# Populate a drop down list with JSON data using JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, drop-down-menu

As the title above says, I am currently trying to populate a drop down list with JSON data using JQuery, I tried adapting an example and came out with this code underneath however it's just populating the list with 'Please Select'. Any advice would be very much appreciated.

```
<script>
    //change module run based on module code/name
    $("#MainContent_ddlModuleCode").change(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetRegJSON",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                var jsonReg = $.parseJSON(data.d);

                //$('#MainContent_ddlModuleRun').empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').html(''));
                $('#MainContent_ddlModuleRun').empty().append($('<option selected="Seleced" value ="0">Please Select</option>'));

                //Loop through
                var matchVal = $("#MainContent_ddlModuleCode option:selected").val();
                jsonReg.ModuleVersions.filter(function (modulecode) {
                    if (modulecode.ModuleRuns != null) {                            
                        $(modulecode.ModuleRuns).each(function (i) {
                            $("#MainContent_ddlModuleRun").append($('<option></option>').val(modulecode.moduleRuns[i].moduleRunUrn).html(modulecode.moduleRuns[i].runName + ' ' + modulecode.moduleRuns[i].runStartDate));
                            $("#MainContent_ddlModuleRun").append('<option>Hello</option>').val('Hello').html('Hello');
                        });
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error: could not retrieve module information.');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Json data is as follows:

```
{
  "AgendaUrn": 21111518,
  "ModuleCredit": 20,
  "ModuleLevel": "3",
  "ModuleRuns": null,
  "moduleCode": "UZZTW-20-3",
  "moduleName": "MATHS"
},
{
  "AgendaUrn": 20437486,
  "ModuleCredit": 20,
  "ModuleLevel": "3",
  "ModuleRuns": [
    {
      "AgendaUrn": 20437486,
      "SiteUrn": 5,
      "moduleRunUrn": 2211291,
      "runName": "17FEB/1",
      "runStartDate": "2018-02-26T00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "AgendaUrn": 20437486,
      "SiteUrn": 5,
      "moduleRunUrn": 2200398,
      "runName": "17MAY/1",
      "runStartDate": "2018-05-14T00:00:00"
    }
  ],
  "moduleCode": "UZ3WR1-20-3",
  "moduleName": "BIOLOGY"
},
```

Comment: What does your json data look like? Could you add this to your question?

Comment: I've added a snippet of some of the JSON

Comment: And what part of the json would you like in your dropdown box

Comment: There is no `d` property in that json. Don't see any property `ModuleVersions` either

Comment: Start back at success and do `console.log(data)`. It will already be an object so no need for `$.parseJSON`. Then as you start iterating through parts of that object use console logging to see what you are working with at any given point

Comment: If the module run is not null then to populate the dropdown list with the different moduleRunUrns